# Pedestrian Position/coordination in anylogic in certain time period

Tags: anylogic

I have a simple pedestrian model where 7000 pedestrians are going from an entry line to target line. I want to know the position of the pedestrians after certain time period for predicting how much time they need for going from one point to another. In anylogic help i saw getX,getY function but where to use these and how?
[Pedestrian Model and Simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxbfn.png)

Comment: Hey there & welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is incomplete and has little chances to get answered as is. Please read the **[How-To-Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** article & edit your question adding more information. Let's start with some snippets that you've worked on regarding the matter! (if you need help with this, read up on how to create a **[Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**)

Comment: you can use ped.getX() in any of the pedestrian library block actions.. you can use agent.getX() in any of the PML blocks actions. You can use getX() anywhere inside the pedestrian agent... you can also in main potentially do pedestrians.get(index).getX().. so it depends on how you want to do whatever you are doing

Comment: @Felipe Thanks. Have you seen my model, it's in the question. I just used 3 blocks pedsource, pedgoto and pedsink, and time measure. And I want is to get each pedestrians positon after 1 second and so on. I wrote ped.getX(),ped.getY() in ped source agentaction,on startup box but i'm getting error. i need the data of each pedestrians position after 1 second, hope you get my question. thanks.

Comment: @Felipe thanks a lot, but i am getting an error which is Description: The method create_GetCoordinates(int, TimeUnits, Pedestrian) is undefined for the type Main. Location: Pedestrian Flow/Main/pedGoTo - PedGoTo.    What should i do?

Comment: @Felipe I tried to drag the Getcoordinates dynamic event to the Main, this time it's running but i cant see the information after 1 second. in model running window it's showing getcordinates but i cant click or get any info. hope you understand. thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a dynamic event called GetCoordinates with 1 argument called ped of type Pedestrian
2. in the pedGoTo block when an agent enters the block you will use this code:

   create_GetCoordinates(1,SECOND,ped);
3. In the GetCoordinates dynamic event you can now use ped.getX() and ped.getY() to collect the information you need after 1 second.

Comment: I tried to drag the Getcoordinates dynamic event to the Main, this time it's running but i cant see the information after 1 second. in model running window it's showing getcordinates but i cant click or get any info. hope you understand. thanks –

Comment: you can use the function traceln( ped.getX() ) to print the value in the console.

Comment: Okay  thanks, but where I'll write that function? Action box of dynamic event? Thanks